# Encoding ISO-8859-15 powershell

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, sms

I need to send an SMS from a powerShell script (using smsmode api). My problem is that the encoding of my message should be in "ISO-8859-15" and eventhough the encoding seems to work in the console, when i receive the sms the encoding is wrong.

This is the code so far to try and encode, but i'm not even sure it works properly. It does affect the output in the console that's for sure.

```
        $encoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('iso-8859-15')
        $stringEncoded = $encoded.GetBytes($messageToSend) 
        $result = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString($stringEncoded)

         $postParam = @{
            accessToken = $smsToken
            numero      = $receivingNumber
            message     = $result
            nbr_msg     = 1 
         }
 $reponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $resourceToSendSMS -Body $postParam
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this or where exactly is the problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Code samples please

Comment: it is the message in the postParam.

Comment: What is the initial encoding of the string in `$messageToSend`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
$dstEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('iso-8859-15')
$srcEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
$result = $dstEncoding.GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::Convert($srcEncoding,$dstEncoding,$srcEncoding.GetBytes($messageToSend)))
```

You basically convert the bytes of the current encoded characters into the destination encoding. Finally, you need to get the string of the converted bytes.

The problem is that if your default encoding doesn't support all characters already in `$messageToSend`, even though the encoding will be correct, the data won't be. So it does depend on how `$messageToSend` was created.

`[System.Text.Encoding]::Default` is the encoding of the active code page. This can vary on different systems.

Comment: well it didn't work, but the encoding of my active code page is already in "iso-8859-15" and the $messageToSend is a string hard coded on the code page.

Comment: You may need to add a charset attribute in your `Invoke-Restmethod -ContentType 'charset="iso-8859-15"'`.

Comment: i've tried almost everything! I'm starting to think that powershell cannot encode in "ISO-8859-15" ...